# $M$ compact iff every open additive cover of $M$ contains $M$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Call an open over $\mathscr{U}$ of a metric space $M$ an *additive cover* if whenever $U,V\in\mathscr{U}$, we have $U\cup V\in \mathscr{U}$. Prove that $M$ is compact if and only if every additive open cover of $M$ contains $M$.

To begin with, I'm quite confused with the phrase "every additive open cover of $M$ contains $M$". Doesn't every open cover of $M$ contain $M$ by definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cover is a set of sets.  To say that it contains $M$ in this context means that $M$ is one of the elements of $\mathscr U$, i.e., one of the sets in the cover.  The definition of cover only says that the *union* of the elements (sets) of the cover contains $M$ *as a subset* (not as an element).

One problem is the ambiguity of the word "contains," which sometimes refers to set membership and other times refers to containment of subsets, a very important distinction to make.

As for the problem itself, here's how one direction can be proved: You can use induction to prove that $\mathscr U$ contains (as an element) every finite union of elements from $\mathscr U$.  You can use the open cover definition of compactness to show that $M$ is a finite union of elements from $\mathscr U$.

**Added**: For the other direction, if you start with an arbitrary cover $\mathcal A$, let $\mathscr U$ be the set of finite unions of elements of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Ah, that definition of "contain" confused me. Thanks! (By the way, I think your solution works for only one direction, unless I'm missing something obvious? I'll think about the other direction first, and I'll ask for a hint if I don't get it.)

Comment: @PJMiller: Oops, I was careless and forgot it was supposed to be both directions.  I probably only did the easy direction.

Comment: @PJMiller: Now I've added something on the other direction.

Comment: Yup, got it now.